# How to pass a custom Object to MenuItem and then retrieve it later?

Tags: android, menu, menuitem, submenu, navigationview

Let's say I get a list of numbers from server, representing chat rooms.

On that event I display them in the `NavigationView` menu by calling in the loop:

```
private NavigationView mNavigationView;
private SubMenu mMenuRooms;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    mMenuRooms = mNavigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.item_rooms).getSubMenu();
}

@Override
public void onTextMessage(WebSocket websocket, String str) throws Exception {
    ...
    for (Room room: rooms) {
        mMenuRooms.add("Chat room #" + room.id).setCheckable(true);
    }
```

Then later I get another request with a single number from the server telling me to "join a particular chat room" and I want to find the corresponding  `MenuItem` and call `setChecked(true)` on that Object:

Currently I have to perform string acrobatics to find that menu item:

```
String title = "Chat room #" + id;
for (int i = mMenuRooms.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    MenuItem item = mMenuRooms.getItem(i);
    item.setChecked(title.equals(item.getTitle()); // a hack using menu item title
}
```

However I would prefer to pass the room number to the menu item as I was creating it - and later retrieve that `Integer` while iterating through the menu.

How to do that please?

In the [MenuItem doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html) there is a method `getMenuInfo()` for retrieving a custom object. But I can not find the sibling method for setting that object...

Answer (score 0):

You should call a method `inValidateOptionMenu();` when you want to update MenuItam above method invokes `onCreateOptionsmenu()` method so you can put checks for your updated value by using global variables and change UI accordingly.

Comment: I am not sure how your `inValidateOptionMenu/onCreateOptionsmenu`-suggestion helps my problem: I would like attach an `Integer` room number to each `MenuItem` - and then retrieve it back later.

Comment: my solution is based on option menu in Action bar or toolbar and if you want to update or display the updated number in menu-item so you can add custom view in ActionView of MenuItem and then retrieve TextView and update your value.